# Retrieve value using key without using iterator in HashMap

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I would like to retrieve value based on the key from **HashMap**. I am able to get the value based in the key from **hashmap** using below code. I have got the perfect result. I believe each time looping for a value from **1000+ records** is not a good idea. It makes application much slower.

Here is the bunch of code with the for loop.

```
 HashMap<Integer, LabelModel> labelHashMap = gson.fromJson(storedHashMapString, type);

    for(Map.Entry<Integer, LabelModel> entry:labelHashMap.entrySet())
    {
        LabelModel label = entry.getValue();
        key = label.getKey();
        if(key != null && !key.isEmpty())
        {
            if(key.equalsIgnoreCase("please_select_governorate"))
            {
                english_label = label.getEnglish();
                arabic_label = label.getArabic();
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not want to make my app slower. So, I would prefer directly retrieving the value with the help of key without using iterator or for loop. How can I achieve this?

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: May i know the reason for the down vote?

Comment: Your questions is confusing, you should be more clear with what you want to achieve. With the way you asked it you already caused 2 people to misunderstand it and answer wrongly.

Comment: @Oleg hope you understood the question now

Comment: Why do you have a String key in the value and an Integer key in the HashMap? All you really need is another HashMap keyed on the String keys, and `map.get(key)`.

Comment: I understood it the first time. It's still confusing, when you say `key from HashMap` it means the key of the `Map` if you want something based on a property called `key` that a value of the `Map` has you should be way more explicit about it. And as @EJP said you should create the mapping you need. With your current map all you can do is loop.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks for the information. Can you change the code?  It would be helpful for me

Comment: You mean edit your question? Make it more clear?

Comment: @Oleg No. actual i would like you to answer this question. I am new to hashmap. Only i could do is that using for loop, get the information. I heard that for loop makes app slow because each time it has to loop to get the data

Comment: Evan already answered it.

Comment: @Oleg Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to do directly, but you could make an initial pass over the whole map and transform it into a map that uses the sting keys as keys.  At least this way you only have to iterate over the whole value set once.

So if you use a method like

```
Map<String, LabelModel> reIndex(HashMap<Integer, LabelModel> labelMap) {
    Map<String, LabelModel> reIndexedLabelMap = new HashMap<>();
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, LabelModel> entry:labelMap.entrySet()) {
        LabelModel label = entry.getValue();
        String key = label.getKey();
        reIndexedLabelMap.put(key.toLowerCase(), label); 
    }
    return reIndexedLabelMap; 
}
```

You can then use this new object to quickly grab any other label by it's String key:

```
Map<String, LabelModel> reIndexed = reIndex(labeHashlMap);
reIndexed.get("please_select_governorate");
reIndexed.get("what_ever_else");
```

Assuming that the keys are unique with respect to case.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg what is that?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Evan

Comment: getting error here. Expression is expected Map<String, LabelModel> reIndex(HashMap<Integer, LabelModel> labelMap)

Answer (score 0):

```
if(labelHashMap.get("something") != null){ code }
```

if you attempt to get a value with a key that does not exist then the hash map will simply return null.

Comment: Your code won't compile. OP's current key is an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do an initial pass i.e iterating over JSON. because mapping from JSON to HashMap is iterative as well, which you can avoid.